# How to allow user to sign in with both email and phone number?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have firebase name and email authentication in my android app. I also have phone number auth in my app.

I want to link name and email with phone, so that user can sign in with phone number and password, if he forgets email or gets bore to type long email.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you want to allow for signing in with either email or phone number, or if you want to allow for the Phone number to be used as a second factor, for sign in, there are different solutions.

If you just want to have the Phone number **be a second way to sign in**, you can link the credentials using the `linkWithCredential` method on your Firebase User. This way you can add as many ways to sign in, as you want. Firebase has a [good guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) on this.

If you want the phone number to `be a second factor of authentication`, you will need to have a custom auth provider, which does the second factor authentication. There is also a [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) on this, however the 2 Factor Authentication part itself would be up to you.